# Indexing a string?

Tags: c++, string, indexing

I'm new to C++ and I've been using python for a while, but I know C++ isn't as user friendly.  How could I index a string, let's say "Example" from 1:6 in C++?  I want to only index the inside elements and not the first or last char.

Comment: I think you're talking about *slicing*, not *indexing*. Slicing takes a subset of a string, such as extracting `"xampl"` from `"Example"`. Indexing usually refers to extracting a single character; for example `"Example"[3] == 'm'`. And for C++ you need to distinguish between C-style strings and `std::string`; the latter are much more flexible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
I want to index the inside elements.
```

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Example";

    if (str.length() > 2)
    {
        std::cout << str.substr(1, str.length() - 2);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << str;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is `xampl`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `substr` function of the `string` class, docs are [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr). I don't believe C++ provides a nice slice operator, you may be able to overload the subscript operator to do it, but I'm not sure.